# Mongoose: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model ""

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make an app with mongodb and nodejs. I've made a special route that has `:id` parameter and it's working well.

And I've made another get route that has `product/:category`. When  I send request to this route everytime I get that error:

```js
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "(here is my req.params.category)" at path "_id" for model "Product"
```

My route is that:

```js
// product is my model I called it in top of the file
app.get('product/:category', async (req, res)=>{
    const productByCategory = await product.find({category: req.params.category});
    res.json(productByCategory);
});
```

When I make get request to the route above I get that error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "(here is my req.params.category)" at path "_id" for model "Product"
```

My Product model is that:

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        min: 40,
        required: true
    },
    category:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    imageUrl:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    comments: [{
        type: Object
    }],
    seller: {
        sellerId:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        username:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        shopName:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        category:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    location: {
        type: "String",
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You rout for `:_id` is this way: `app.get('product/:_id'`?

Comment: @Valijon No I want to route for category.

Comment: Post all routes please

Comment: @Valijon your code worked for me. No need to post all routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`product/:_id` and `product/:category` are the "same" in route context... So, even if you send `product/:category` request, server computes first endpoint that matches.

**Solution 1:** Make each route *unique*.

```
// _id
app.get('product/_id/:_id', async (req, res)=>{
    const productById = await product.find({_id: req.params._id});
    res.json(productById);
});

// category
app.get('product/category/:category', async (req, res)=>{
    const productByCategory = await product.find({category: req.params.category});
    res.json(productByCategory);
});

...
```

**Solution 2:** Use `request.body`

```
app.post('product', async (req, res)=>{
    const product = await product.find(req.body});
    res.json(product);
});
```

**Note:** Be aware NoSQL injection.

https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/tree/master/NoSQL%20Injection